# Kill ssh session and/or stuck processes

Tags: ssh, cpu, process, kill, top

I'm developing with vi over ssh.

My problem is that sometimes I get my ssh connection killed because of my poor wifi connection and previous processes (like "top", "rails c", etc...) are not being killed properly.

So after a little while, i get those processes at 100% of the CPU usage (i don't really know why), and I need to kill them manually.

Because I'm not the only developer, it can get really messy so my boss asked me to come up with a solution.

How would i do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ssh -t` Seems to work as I wanted.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways around this:

1. Kill the leftover processes.
2. Use something to compensate for the disconnections.

The second option is the easiest with `screen` or `tmux`.

After your connection has dropped you reconnect, log back in and resume your screen/tmux session, then continue working where you left.   (For screen use `screen -r` to resume).

If you ever used remote desktop in windows, then you can compare this with resuming a disconnected RDP session.

Comment: I also use `screen` in such situations as well. Good answer. +1.

Comment: Can you tell me how to kill the leftover processes?

Comment: First get the process ID of the leftover process.  Use can use a command such as `ps` for this. Then use `'kill -1 processID`. This will send the process a SIGHUP. Loosely translated this will tell the process "User has disconnected. Please end yourself in a proper way'. Most programs which receive this signal will save files, close databases etc. If that fails use `kill -15 ` or `kill -9` (-15 is terminate to the process. Like -1 but more insistent. -15 is not sent to the process but to the OS. It is a 'kill with prejeduce' command which might leave a mess.

Comment: You probably can't do this automatically. The dropped [WiFi] connection should already have caused the shell on the other and to signal all processes with SIGHUP before terminating itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ssh with an unreliable connection, you may want to give mosh a try: http://mosh.mit.edu/

Mosh was exactly written for this purpose. Note that you need it installed on both sides.